# Is there any way to get READ access to a file opened in exclusive access ie FILE_SHARE_NONE

Tags: windows

Without doing dirty and nasty ways, I believe this to be not allowable from user mode, even with SE_BACKUP_NAME.

Things I consider dirty and nasty:

1. Figuring out what process owns the handle and writing code to run in that process and close the handle.
2. Reading/parsing the MFT/FAT table
3. Using a Kernel Driver

Comment: Using kernel-mode drivers this is possible. You need either a kernel-mode driver which will open the handle for you. Our RawDisk product in particular does the job.

Comment: Implicit in the " I believe this to be not allowable from *user mode* " is that yes you can do it from kernel mode.

Comment: Well, with the third-party driver you can do it in user mode. Yes, you need to install the driver but you don't need to write one.

Comment: yes but I think we are splitting hairs here.  I was more interested in a stock solution on windows without resorting to cheating via kernel access/installing a driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, although it may not suit your needs; it isn't dirty or nasty, but it's heavy, i.e., it is not straightforward to code and it creates a disproportionate amount of system load if you're just trying to read a single file.

However, if you need to do this, this is the only reasonable and safe solution I'm aware of: see the MSDN documentation on the [Volume Shadow Copy Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Most backup software uses VSS nowadays.

Comment: very interesting point and indeed it's heavy.  It may not solve my purposes ( but I didn't expect there to be anything close to a solution). I'll take a deeper look before awarding you the answer.